# WPF: Change Style of an element in an Inherited Theme

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpftoolkit, charts

I want to change the style of a theme an inherited style (inherited through based on). Have any idea? This is basically to define multiple styles for multi-series charts in wpf toolkit. Code looks as follows:

```
<Style x:Key="A" TargetType="DVC:ColumnDataPoint">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="DVC:ColumnDataPoint">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Opacity="0" x:Name="Root">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Name="columngrid">
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <Style x:Key="aquaboarder" TargetType="Border">
                                <Style.Resources>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="BackBrush" StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#B211B9D8" Offset="0.1" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF0F56C7" Offset="0.9" />
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Style.Resources>
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackBrush}"/>
                            </Style>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <Border Name="columnBorder" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="20,20,0,0" Style="{StaticResource aquaboarder}">
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>                                             
                    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding FormattedDependentValue}" />
                    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And the inherited style goes as follows:

```
<Style x:Key="B" BasedOn="{StaticResource A}"  TargetType="DVC:ColumnDataPoint">
    <Style.Resources>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="BackBrush" StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
            <GradientStop Color="#B24DE509" Offset="0.1" />
            <GradientStop Color="#FF238910" Offset="0.9" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Style.Resources>           
</Style>
```

I want to set the **columngrid** in "style A" to use the backbrush defined in "style B". I do not like to do more stuff in style B as I will have many of inherited styles be defined just changing this style afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wasting the perfectly useful `Background` property that is already available and trying to create a new one that serves the same purpose.  Since you are overriding the control template, just use the `Background` for the purpose that charting intended.  Instead of setting it to transparent in your style, let your derived style set or override `Background` and then use `{TemplateBinding Background}` in the control template where are you current using `{StaticResource Backbrush}`.  Your other use of `{TemplateBinding Background}` on the `Grid` element you can remove since it seems clear that your intention is that the grid background will be transparent.

Comment: Hi Rick, Thanks for the answer and sorry for the late comment. I just got some valuable idea out and implemented in the creation of the chart. I have another problem, I want to let all the charts share a common color theme. Thus I would like the background colors for different columns etc to be inherited from the colors defined in the chart palette. In this case what should I do? Currently as soon as I override a data point series type (eg column data point) I get only Orange color. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The easiest way is to bind background to a property in the data context and set the color there.  This technique is described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/02/04/columns-of-a-different-color-customizing-the-appearance-of-silverlight-charts-with-re-templating-and-mvvm.aspx

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks again for your helpful comments and answers. I will go through the content in the link you provided and try getting things working.:-)